# postgresql_exporter is not working. how to configure it?

Tags: postgresql, docker, prometheus, grafana

I am trying to run postgres_exporter (according to this link:https://github.com/prometheus-community/postgres_exporter) and I want read those metrics from prometheus server. My postgresql database is running in a docker container on port:5432 Database Name: praxin Username: testuser Password: passuser

This is the command, with that i tried to run postgresql_exporter: docker run --net=host -e DATA_SOURCE_NAME="postgresql://testuser:passuser@localhost:5432/praxin?sslmode=disable" -p 9187:9187 quay.io/prometheuscommunity/postgres-exporter

It shows postgresql_exporter is running on port 9187, when i go to browser, it doesnt show any metrics and is not connecting. Where might have i been gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

testuser does not have SELECT access to the database metrics tables

grant SELECT ON pg_stat_database to testuser;

Use this command and to grant access for a metrics table is postgres

Otherwise use default user postgres

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helpful for someone.

The database user you are using in combination with the postgres-exporter needs to have following permissions:

```
GRANT pg_monitor to <USERNAME>;
```

`pg_monitor` is built-in role that allow administrators to easily set permissions for the purpose of monitoring the database server.

For more information have a look at https://github.com/prometheus-community/postgres_exporter#running-as-non-superuser